# The correct way to linearize colorspace before resizing, blurring etc

Tags: image-processing, color, physics, conversion

There was an [interesting discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/161zLDfpGBs/Rtl5AM4Uki4J) on MathGroup dealing with the fact that image-processing functions in *Mathematica* (and many other software, including Adobe Photoshop) work with RGB, Grayscale etc. intensity values as if they would be linear and additive while in fact these values are powers of the *physical* intensity values and consequently must be linearized before making additive operations on them. This topic is expanded in [the linked article](http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html) where examples of incorrect default image resizing and blurring are given along with the general explanation of the correct algorithm and images generated with it.

Matthias Odisio (Wolfram Research) [replied](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/161zLDfpGBs/lC9Fj4ayEywJ):

> This genuine issue will be properly addressed in a future release of
> Mathematica.

So, *Mathematica* 9 is released. But I cannot find any example in the Documentation on how to linearize a colorspace correctly. Obviously, the linearization algorithm must depend on the colorspace used.

The question is: is there efficient and straightforward way to linearize a colorspace in *Mathematica* correctly?

### UPDATE

Here is an excerpt [from the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS61A9D13D-919A-4010-A3A2-00477A81FDB0a.html#WS2A3CEB0E-F1A1-4035-9C62-CFF4A0527B11a) for Adobe After Effects which highlights some benefits of linear color space:

> By performing operations in a linear color space, you can prevent
> certain edge and halo artifacts, such as the fringing that appears
> when high-contrast, saturated colors are blended together. Many color
> operations benefit from working in a linear color space, including
> those operations involved in image resampling, blending between layers
> with blending modes, motion blur, and anti-aliasing.
>
> <...>
>
> *Note: A
> linearized working color space works best with higher color depths—16
> bpc and 32 bpc—and is not recommended for 8-bpc color.*

Also, good explanation of the difference between linear RGB and sRGB color spaces can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894053/590388).

Comment: A very interesting question highlighting an issue of which I was only partially aware.

Comment: I've tested this with (industrial) cameras, grayvalues were practically linear. So this is probably not a property of the color space, but of the camera type and analog/digital preprocessing done in the camera. But if it isn't linear - why not just use ImageApply before resizing?

Comment: @nikie `ImageApply` is an option but it is not straighforward because the used must define transformation functions for every colorspace by himself based on the colorspace specifications. It is not obvious and requires substantial work for anyone who is not deeply in image processing (like me). I also concerned about efficiency.

Comment: I don't have Mathematica 9, but the online documentation shows that [`ColorConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorConvert.html) has been updated to include CIE XYZ, and there is also a new symbol `ColorProfileData` for representing ICC color profiles. So I think you should be able to `ColorConvert` from whatever color space to XYZ, do the resizing and blurring, then `ColorConvert` back to the original color space (or any other you choose).

Comment: @Simon Woods Are the XYZ colorspace values additive?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I believe XYZ is a linear colorspace, yes. The best thing would be to test it using one of the images from the article you linked to.

Comment: @Simon Woods Unfortunately, `ImageResize` gives wrong result after converting to the `"XYZ"` colospace: `img=Import["http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_dalai_lama_gray.jpg"];ImageResize[ColorConvert[img,"XYZ"],Scaled[1/2]]`. From the other side, linearized sRGB colorspace produces expected result when `ImageResize` is applied (see code in the [linked discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/161zLDfpGBs/Rtl5AM4Uki4J)).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, that's a shame. Hopefully Matthias will get back to you with a solution.

Comment: Thanks to the new features in M9, you could develop this very fine solution using color profiles (second column in your answer). This is clearly my preferred approach for this problem. What is somehow lacking now is a color profile reader/editor so that one does not have to hunt for magic numbers like 256/563 which you used. Please keep in mind that image processing is applied to many domains where pixel data have arbitrary (or even no) physical units; for these cases M's implementation is the most appropriate; the issue you mention is nearly marginal, and M9 allows for an elegant workaround.

Comment: Anything new to mention with regard to *Mathematica* 10?

Comment: @MatthiasOdisio Currently it is documented that for `ColorConvert` the `"RGB"` colorspace is assumed to be the sRGB colorspace. Why not to introduce the `"LinearRGB"` colorspace? It is easy to implement and would be very convenient.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you know your data belongs to a specific color space, then you should specify it. See my answer.

Answer (score 27):

Here is my attempt to figure out how the correct colorspace linearization should be made. I used specially designed test images by Eric Brasseur for comparison of two colorspace linearization algorithms. The first algorithm is just an implementation of the corresponding formulae from the [Specification of sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) made by Jari Paljakka who started [the discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/161zLDfpGBs/Rtl5AM4Uki4J) on MathGroups. This algorithm does not take into acount the alpha channel (and probably will work incorrectly with it).
The second algorithm utilizes new image processing functionality of *Mathematica* 9: the support of colorprofiles.

Both algorithms assume that the input image is in the sRGB colorspace which [is the most commonly-used color space](http://regex.info/blog/photo-tech/color-spaces-page1) and also [is the standard default color space for the Internet](http://www.color.org/srgb.xalter). More than 90% of all images in the Internet are sRGB-encoded.

The problem with the sRGB colorspace is that it does not have pure gamma curve and hence cannot be correctly linearized just by applying gamma to RGB values. But there is a [pure gamma based colorspace: Adobe RGB 1998](http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/AdobeRGB1998.pdf). So I decided to convert an image to Adobe RGB 1998, then linearize the colorspace by applying gamma using `ImageAdjust`, resize it with `ImageResize` (which operates under the assumption of linearity for the pixel data), then apply `ImageAdjust` with inverse gamma of Adobe RGB 1998 and finally convert from Adobe RGB 1998 to sRGB.

Here is a comparison of the results (these screenshots should be seen in original size with 100% resolution; the code follows):

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]

The NASA image "[Earth's City Lights](http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/ve//1438/earth_lights_4800.tif)" is a very extreme case where non-linear colorspace effects have a big impact on the results of resizing the image (reference from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize_colorspace)):

[image: screenshot5]

```
(*Color profile based approach*)
(*The AdobeRGB1998.icc profile is from \
http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/adobergb.html*)
adobeRGB1998 = Import["AdobeRGB1998.icc"];
(*http://scarse.sourceforge.net/goodies/profiles/*)
sRGB = Import[
   "http://scarse.sourceforge.net/goodies/profiles/spaces/sRGB.icm"];
sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg_Image] := 
 ImageAdjust[
  ColorConvert[
   Image[sRGBimg, "Real",(*ColorSpace->sRGB,*)Interleaving -> True], 
   sRGB -> adobeRGB1998], {0, 0, 563/256}]
linear2sRGB[linearRGB_Image] := 
 ColorConvert[
  Image[ImageAdjust[linearRGB, {0, 0, 256/563}], 
   Interleaving -> True], adobeRGB1998 -> sRGB]
linearResize[sRGBimg_Image, scaling_] := 
 linear2sRGB[ImageResize[sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg], scaling]]
linearBlur[sRGBimg_Image, r_] := 
 linear2sRGB[Blur[sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg], r]]
linear2Grayscale[sRGBimg_Image] := 
 ImageAdjust[
  ColorConvert[sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg], "Grayscale"], {0, 0, 256/563}]


(*functional approach*)
srgb2linear = 
  Compile[{{Csrgb, _Real, 1}}, 
   With[{α = 0.055}, 
    Table[Piecewise[{{C/12.92, 
        C <= 0.04045}, {((C + α)/(1 + α))^2.4, 
        C > 0.04045}}], {C, Csrgb}]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
linear2srgb = 
  Compile[{{Clinear, _Real, 1}}, 
   With[{α = 0.055}, 
    Table[Piecewise[{{12.92*C, 
        C <= 0.0031308}, {(1 + α)*C^(1/2.4) - α, 
        C > 0.0031308}}], {C, Clinear}]], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
linearresize[sRGBimg_Image, scaling_] := 
 Image[linear2srgb[
   ImageData[
    ImageResize[
     Image[srgb2linear[
       ImageData[ColorConvert[Image[sRGBimg, "Real"], "RGB"], 
        Interleaving -> True]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"], scaling], 
    Interleaving -> True]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
linearblur[sRGBimg_Image, r_] := 
 Image[linear2srgb[
   ImageData[
    Blur[Image[
      srgb2linear[
       ImageData[ColorConvert[Image[sRGBimg, "Real"], "RGB"], 
        Interleaving -> True]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"], r], 
    Interleaving -> True]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
linear2grayscale[sRGBimg_Image] := 
 Image[linear2srgb[
   ImageData[
    ColorConvert[
     Image[srgb2linear[
       ImageData[ColorConvert[Image[sRGBimg, "Real"], "RGB"], 
        Interleaving -> True]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"], "Grayscale"], 
    Interleaving -> True]]]


(*comparison*)
testImages = 
  Import /@ \
{"http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_dalai_lama_gray.jpg", 
    "http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_colors.jpg", 
    "http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_2.2.jpg"};
testImages[[3]] = ImageRotate[testImages[[3]]];
correctResults = 
  Import /@ \
{"http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_dalai_lama_gray_good.jpg", 
    "http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_colors_good.jpg", 
    "http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_good_2.2.jpg"};
correctResults[[3]] = ImageRotate[correctResults[[3]]];
fullSizeFix = 
  Style[Image[#, Magnification -> 1], Magnification -> 1] &;
correctResults = fullSizeFix /@ correctResults;
Grid[Prepend[
  Join[Map[fullSizeFix, {ImageResize[#, Scaled[1/2]], 
       linearResize[#, Scaled[1/2]], linearresize[#, Scaled[1/2]]} & /@
      testImages, {2}], List /@ correctResults, 2], 
  Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     TextAlignment -> Center] & /@ {"Just\nImageResize", 
    "ColorProfile-based\nlinearized resizing", 
    "Functional\nlinearized resizing", 
    "Expected result\n(Eric Brasseur)"}], Frame -> All]


calliphora = 
  Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/\
Calliphora_sp_Portrait.jpg"];
calliphoraCorrect = 
  Import["http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_calliphora_sp_\
portrait.1.jpg"];
calliphoraSize = ImageDimensions[calliphoraCorrect];
saturn = Import[
   "http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpegMod/PIA11667_modest.jpg"];
saturnCorrect = 
  Import["http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_388135main_pia11667.\
1.jpg"];
saturnSize = ImageDimensions[saturnCorrect];
Grid[{Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     TextAlignment -> Center] & /@ {"Just\nImageResize", 
    "ColorProfile-based\nlinearized resizing", 
    "Functional\nlinearized resizing", 
    "Expected result\n(Eric Brasseur)"}, 
  fullSizeFix /@ {ImageResize[calliphora, calliphoraSize], 
    linearResize[calliphora, calliphoraSize], 
    linearresize[calliphora, calliphoraSize], calliphoraCorrect},
  fullSizeFix /@ {ImageResize[saturn, saturnSize], 
    linearResize[saturn, saturnSize], 
    linearresize[saturn, saturnSize], saturnCorrect}}]

Grid[{Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     TextAlignment -> Center] & /@ {"Just\nBlur[#,2]&", 
    "ColorProfile-based\nlinearized blur", 
    "Functional\nlinearized blur", 
    "Expected result\n(Eric Brasseur)"}, 
  fullSizeFix /@ {Blur[testImages[[1]], 2], 
    linearBlur[testImages[[1]], 2], linearblur[testImages[[1]], 2], 
    Import["http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_dalai_lama_gray_\
blurred.1.jpg"]}}]


gamma4 = Import[
   "http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_color_to_grayscale_start.\
jpg"];
Grid[{Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     TextAlignment -> 
      Center] & /@ {"Just\nColorConvert[#,\"Grayscale\"]&", 
    "ColorProfile-based\nlinearization", "Functional\nlinearization", 
    "Expected result\n(Eric Brasseur)"}, 
  fullSizeFix /@ {ColorConvert[gamma4, "Grayscale"], 
    linear2Grayscale[gamma4], linear2grayscale[gamma4], 
    Import["http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_color_to_grayscale_\
good.jpg"]}}]


earthLights = 
  Import["http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/ve//1438/earth_lights_4800.\
tif"];
fullSizeFix = 
  Style[Image[#, Magnification -> 1], Magnification -> 1] &;
Grid[{fullSizeFix /@ {ImageResize[earthLights, 500], 
     linearResize[earthLights, 500], linearresize[earthLights, 500]}, 
   Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      TextAlignment -> Center] & /@ {"Just\nImageResize", 
     "ColorProfile-based\nlinearized resizing", 
     "Functional\nlinearized resizing"}
   } // Transpose]
```

Comment: Everything looks good except the halftone patterns at the bottom of the first image.  The two middle results do not match the target on the right. (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suspect that the reason is that the Eric Brasseur's test images were lossy JPEG-encoded by him in order to get reasonable size of the web-page (he noticed this in the text). The "expected" resulting images probably were generated from the original lossless images. I cannot be completely sure but I think that lossy compression may cause the mentioned differences.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But of course this does not explain differences in other images, especially for the Saturn image. Eric did not mention what algorithm he used for image resizing. It is possible that selecting other resizing method could give closer match...

Comment: The solution based on color profile is very fine indeed. The differences with the so-called "expected result" have no significance.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov The same problems appear if an image is rotated. How would an implementation of a function for linearized rotation of an image look like in the methods you provide?

Comment: Also, is there a way to keep transparency (alpha channel) when using the adobe method?

Comment: @Kagaratsch For linear rotation it one can use  `linearRotate[sRGBimg_Image,\[Theta]_,size_:Automatic]:=linear2sRGB[ImageRotate[sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg],\[Theta],size]];` (color profile-based approach).

Comment: Wow, thanks! Unfortunately this only becomes really useful if the alpha channel of a picture is preserved. I did some testing and it seems the above color profile based routine replaces transparency with white color.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Try `AlphaChannel[sRGB2Linear[<put image with transparency here>]]`. You will see that transparency is preserved on linearization.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Actually the functional approach also preserves the alpha channel: `AlphaChannel[linearresize[#, Scaled@1]] == AlphaChannel[#] &[<put image with transparency here>]` returns `True`.

Comment: I tried `AlphaChannel[sRGB2Linear[ myImg ]]` on an `Import`ed .png image `myImg` that has transparent regions, and got a blank image as an output, with all the colors gone. Not sure if it is supposed to work this way...

Comment: If I use the above `linearRotate` on `myImg`, the image does rotate but the transparent region becomes white color. This is easy to check by overlapping with a different image as in `Show[{difImg , linearRotate[myImg]}]`.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Please read [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlphaChannel.html): `AlphaChannel` returns a grayscale image. And you are fooled by the white background: try `Overlay[{linearRotate[myImg, 1], linearRotate[myImg, -1]}]` to see that transparency works as expected.

Comment: Strange, I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/wiPNE.png if I apply what you suggest to http://i.stack.imgur.com/rq5RO.png . I did import the profiles correctly, since Mathematica does not complain. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: @Kagaratsch On my system (version 10.2 on Win7 x64) I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/oa6EdJ2.png). What *Mathematica* version do you use and what is your OS?

Comment: I use Mathematica 9 (version 9.0.1.0) on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Maybe they updated the "AdobeRGB1998.icc" file which made it incompatible? The package they offer now is for Photoshop CS4, which might be more recent than 2012 when you first wrote your answer.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I downloaded the color profiles again ([direct download link for windows](http://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/iccprofiles/win/AdobeICCProfilesCS4Win_end-user.zip)) and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the file I got. I guess I will have to play around with it some more and see if I can fix it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

It is arbitrary to assign a color space to data that do not have one attached to them.

What about using "XYZ" if one is looking for a linear color space?

```
i = Import@"http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma_dalai_lama_gray.jpg";
ColorConvert[i, "XYZ"] // ImageResize[#, Scaled[1/2]] & // 
ColorConvert[#, "RGB"] &
```

[image]

Comment: The result of applying an image processing algorithm strongly depends on the colorspace (and the `"XYZ"` colorspace will give different result than any other colorspace). And there are cases when exactly the *linear* RGB colorspace is necessary as [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86441/280) (see the "UPDATE" section). It is a snag that we have no obvious way to distinguish between the physically reasonable linear RGB colorspace and the artificial sRGB colorspace in *Mathematica*!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, what is the motivation behind all your messages ? That page from Eric Brasseur that you are referencing exactly advocates for the solution I describe: Go to a linear space, like XYZ, and do these computations that need to be performed there.   Remember that users can embed anything into an image, not just readings from a CCD sensor.

Comment: It is great to have available in *Mathematica* XYZ, LAB, LUV etc. but the most commonly used colorspace is still RGB and by default it is always sRGB. The intuitively obvious way to study the differences between colorspaces and the image processing algorithms is to begin with the linear RGB colorspace for which most of algorithms are originally designed and only *then* try something such advanced as XYZ or LAB. My point is that something what have to serve as a start for any person (including myself) who is interested in learning image processing algorithms is not available. Isn't it a snag?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Many would disagree with some of your points. What is "intuitively obvious" to you is not at all for quite a few others.  By the way, have you compared the gamuts of "XYZ" and of "AdobeRGB1968" using ChromaticityPlot3D?

Comment: The XYZ colorspace has evident advantage for natural image processing because it is perceptual colorspace and has wider gamut. The linear RGB colorspace has advantage for technical applications because it gives physically reasonable representation of what the digital sensors actually record. The latter is what I call "intuitively obvious": any photo is created by a digital camera which records responses of its digital sensors of three types (Red, Green, Blue). When developing the understanding of digital photography it is natural to start from what the camera actually records and [continued]

Comment: [continued from previous comment] only after this to realize how the camera recordings are related to what we perceive. An availability of linear RGB colorspace is a very basic thing which helps to develop the right picture of digital photography and its relation to image processing. And linear RGB colorspace is actually *necessary* for physical applications like the one I referenced above and like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91748/280).

Comment: BTW The OpenEXR (.exr) format ([as well as DPX, CIN and HDR formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color-management.php)) assumes that RGB channel values are encoded in the Linear RGB colorspace. Currently *Mathematica* imports such files like usual sRGB-encoded PNG, JPG etc. and because of this renders them incorrectly (too dark), try `Import["ExampleData/Balls.exr"]`. For correct rendering one needs to convert them into the sRGB colorspace what currently is not possible using `ColorConvert`. Isn't this a good reason to add the `"LinearRGB"` colorspace to `ColorConvert`?