# Turn Image into graphic

Tags: image-processing

I'm doing an experiment on Zeeman effect, and I have to turn an image into a graphic, like the example below:

[image: Example of the desired result[1]]

What functions available does this image processing?

Thanks in advance,

Gabriel

1 -
 http://www.ifsc.usp.br/~lavfis/images/BDApostilas/ApEfZeeman/EfeitoZeeman_Davidovich.pdf

Comment: Something like `ListPlot@Mean@ImageData[img]`

Comment: Well, it worked. Not as fine as in the example, but maybe that's because of the quality of the images I got in the lab. Thanks a lot!

If someone knows another way to do that, I'd appreciate, to compare the results.

Gabriel

Comment: you would likely get a sharper plot if you grabbed one row of pixels instead of the mean.  `ListPlot@ImageData[[n]]` where `n` is half the image height

Comment: @george2079 Not a good idea with noisy data. The line patterns in the image are almost vertical so taking the mean of a column is a nice way to get a stable measure for the intensity.

Comment: The image is most likely sRGB-encoded, hence consider converting it into Linear RGB: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need the separated image for one of those measurements:

[image]

and then you can use something along the lines

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI1O1.png"];
grayData = ImageData[ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel@img, "Grayscale"], "Real"];
ListLinePlot@Mean[grayData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for your help and your time! 

Gabriel