# How to replicate v9's color conversion to LAB under v10

Tags: color, version-10, version-9, conversion, compatibility

Mathematica 10(.0.0) appears to use a different flavor of the LAB color space, but I would like to emulate the same behavior observed in version 9(.0.0).

### v9

```
Brown
(*RGBColor[0.6, 0.4, 0.2]*)

ColorConvert[Brown, "RGB" -> "LAB"]
(*{0.714252,0.0598271,0.283735}*)
```

### v10

```
Brown // FullForm
(*RGBColor[0.6`,0.4`,0.2`]*)

ColorConvert[Brown, "RGB" -> "LAB"] // FullForm
(*LABColor[0.4802420048160916`, 0.17425620426156752`, 0.3687165422680724`]*)
```

v10 `ColorConversion`'s documentation mentions a D50 white point and `LABColor`'s even lists some formulas, but v9's docs avoid the subject completely.

Which conversion is correct? Are they equivalent, only with a different ["black magic"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57389/convert-spectral-distribution-to-rgb-color/57464#comment164743_57464) color space parameter? And, if so, how could I replicate v9's results under v10?

Comment: Related: [7483](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/how-to-calculate-mix-of-4-colors-defined-in-cielab-lab-model).  One of the answers replicates the V9 conversion.

Comment: v9's lightness of 0.71 is far too light to be brown. Here's [an independent implementation of RGB to Lab conversion](http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab), whose results are close to v10's (although slightly different because it uses a D65 white point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had [implemented my own color conversion functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101627/9490) previously so that I could convert to the Msh color space, a polar version of LAB, so I thought I'd give it a go.

To do the color conversion, you have to know what [reference white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant) value is being used.  The numeric values can be found [here](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_ChromAdapt.html) where they are referred to as *reference illuminant tristimulus values*.  Next you need a transformation matrix to go from sRGB to XYZ color spaces, and the exact matrix you use depends again on the reference white.

Version 10 uses a D50 reference for XYZ and LAB, while version 9 seems to have used a D65 (but this is a small difference and not enough to account for the dramatically different values you find).

Here is what happens in version 10:

```
rgb2labV10[r_, g_, b_] := Module[{
   referenceWhite = {96.42, 100.0, 82.49},
   transformation = {
     {0.4360747`, 0.3850649`, 0.1430804`},
     {0.2225045`, 0.7168786`, 0.0606169`},
     {0.0139322`, 0.0971045`, 0.7141733`}
     },
   rgblinear, x, y, z, f},
  (*Transform RGB to linear RGB *)

  rgblinear = 
   If[# > .04045, ((# + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4, #/12.92] & /@ {r, g, b};
  (*Transform linear RGB to XYZ *)
  {x, y, z} = 
   100 transformation.rgblinear;

  (*Transform XYZ to LAB *)

  f = If[((#) > 0.008856), (#^(1/3)), (7.787 # + 4/29.)] &;
  {x, y, z} = f /@ ({x, y, z}/referenceWhite);
  {116.0 (y - 4./29), 500.0 (x - y), 200 (y - z)}/100
  ]

rgb2labV10[.6, .4, .2]
(* {0.480242, 0.174275, 0.368625} *)
```

For some reason, in the previous version, *Mathematica* omits the step of first converting to linear RGB color - even though this seems to be the norm.  See [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=02), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation), and [here](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_to_XYZ.html) for example.

The conversion is therefore given by

```
rgb2labV9[r_, g_, b_] := Module[{
   referenceWhite = {95.047, 100.0, 108.883},
   transformation = {
     {0.4124564`, 0.3575761`, 0.1804375`},
     {0.2126729`, 0.7151522`, 0.072175`},
     {0.0193339`, 0.119192`, 0.9503041`}
     },
   x, y, z, f},
  (*Transform linear RGB to XYZ *)
  {x, y, z} = 
   100 transformation.{r, g, b};

  (*Transform XYZ to LAB *)

  f = If[((#) > 0.008856), (#^(1/3)), (7.787 # + 4/29.)] &;
  {x, y, z} = f /@ ({x, y, z}/referenceWhite);
  {116.0 (y - 4./29), 500.0 (x - y), 200 (y - z)}/100
  ]


rgb2labV9[.6, .4, .2]
(* {0.714258, 0.0598473, 0.283741} *)
```

Comment: If waiting a year is what it takes to have a nice answer like this one, so be it! I have a few other unanswered questions *wink wink*

Comment: You accounted for chromatic adaptation in this case, yes?

Comment: @J.M., ja - I followed the formulas from [this site](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_ChromAdapt.html)

Comment: It bothers me slightly that I only have accuracy up to about 4 decimal places, but I suppose that *Mathematica* might truncate their conversion matrices a little bit more than Bruce Lindbloom does.

Comment: Why is it that Mathematica and MatLab can't get colorspaces right? They both seem to have a lot of errors in their built-in color functions. D65 is the standard illuminant, not D50. But you might need D50 if you are working with ICC profiles for printing (the print industry uses D50. Everyone else, including the paper and ink industries, use D65 — figure that one out, LOL). Illuminants and chromatic adaptation should be abstracted away from the color spaces. Neither XYZ nor LAB, LUV or other requires any particular illuminant, and there are plenty of reasons to be flexible on this.

Comment: And to add: as you noted, sRGB MUST be linearized before doing any of the matrix transforms. Or your results will be totally out of whack.