# How can I use Kenneth Moreland's "Diverging Color Maps for Scientific Visualization" in plots?

Tags: graphics, color, visualization

I often want to plot two dimensional data that is centered around zero (for me, this is usually a 2D optical spectroscopy signal, but there are other cases), and the MATLAB "Jet" color scheme is ubiquitous in my field.  I find this scheme to be horrendously ugly, and others have written at length at how bad it is for conveying information: see [here](https://github.com/djoshea/matlab-utils/blob/master/libs/perceptuallyImprovedColormaps/Rainbow%20Color%20Map%20-Still-%20Considered%20Harmful.pdf), [here](http://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/81137_92238v00_RainbowColorMap_57312.pdf), and [here](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/the-rainbow-is-deadlong-live-the-rainbow-part-3/) for just a sample.  One of the main problems is that the perceptual changes in the color don't go at a uniform rate across the map. There are regions where the colors appear to change much faster, leading to the appearance of perceived bands.  Nor does the luminosity follow any type of pattern, such that people with color deficiencies can have trouble reading the data.

For showcasing data where there is a lot of zero-values and some positive and negative features, the Jet scheme results in a field of bright green, with positive and negative features shown in red and blue, all of which is oversaturated.  *Mathematica* has done well to avoid this color map altogether, yet I have been called upon to use it on occasion so I took the trouble to import it from MATLAB.

The problem is highlighted by the following sample code (the first line imports a few custom color maps including Jet),

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sqYFdrkY";
showcolorfunction[color_] := 
  With[{opts = {PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> color, 
      PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 200}},
   Column[{
     DensityPlot[
      Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -π, π}, 
      FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/4, opts],
     DensityPlot[
      10 Cos[x^2] Exp[y], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -π, 0}, 
      FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/2, opts], 
     DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
      FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1/10, opts]}, Center, 0]
   ];
showcolorfunction@JetCM
```

[image]

*Mathematica*'s default color scheme (in version 10) whose name I don't know, is much better, as is MATLAB's new default scheme "Parula",

```
showcolorfunction /@ {Automatic, ParulaCM}
```

[image]

but neither of these does what I want here, which is to assign a "special" color to zero.  What I would like is an implementation of Kenneth Moreland's [diverging color maps](http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/).  In his paper linked there, he describes a recipe for creating a continuous diverging color map starting from any two RGB colors, by converting to linear-RGB, then XYZ, then CIELAB, and finally into Msh, a polar-coordinate version of CIELAB.

On his page there are implementations of this recipe in VTK, python, MATLAB, and R - but nothing for *Mathematica*

Comment: To get you started look at `RGBColor`, `LABColor` (et al), `Blend`, `ColorConvert`. Maybe try to replicate the algorithm in the matlab code linked from the website.

Comment: "whose name I don't know" - `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`.

Comment: @J.M. - thank you.  They really went out of their way to give it a catchy name, didn't they?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, Sorry, I was trying to post the question and answer at the same time, but I pressed the wrong button.

Comment: The built-in `"ThermometerColors"` is pretty similar, though zero is slightly yellowish rather than a neutral grey.

Comment: @Rahul, that's sort of the reason why I prefer that to `"RedBlueTones"`.

Comment: Say, @JasonB., did you ever find a solution that satisfied your want of `…"which is to assign a "special" color to zero…"`? Because you clearly achieved the part of your question mentioned just after, regarding the Kenneth Moreland implementations.

Comment: @CATrevillian - I am pretty sure I asked the question at the time because I had already implemented my answer for a project I was working on at the time and wanted to share.  Reading the question and looking at the accepted answer I would expect the 'special' color to be configurable, like an optional argument or option.  But `DivergentColorFunc` just assumes the special value is white. (do I misunderstand your question?)

Comment: Looking back, I would want `DivergentColorFunc` to allow me to specify an arbitrary color for zero, an arbitrary value for zero, and probably a scaling function.

Comment: @JasonB. I think you definitely understand my question! I’ll have to look at your answer a bit more to see if I can spot where and how to insert the color control, at least. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of converting the pseudocode from Moreland's paper into a package.  I had to [change the numerical values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101705/9490) of the RGB->XYZ transformation matrix to account for the fact that *Mathematica* uses different reference white points for the different color spaces.

**Update** This function is available in the [function repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DivergentColorFunction), and the source code is available on [github](https://github.com/jasondbiggs/DivergentColorMaps).  Much thanks to J.M., I've changed a few functions around to make them simpler - but I have kept all the color conversion functions because I like them for clarity, and they don't slow it down compared to the built-in `ColorConvert` function.

```
BeginPackage["DivergentColorMaps`"]

DivergentColorFunc::usage = "DivergentColorFunc[{r1,g1,b1},{r2,b2,g2}] returns a continuously diverging color map which interpolates between two RGB colors.\n
DivergentColorFunc[color1, color2] takes two color objecst as input and returns a continuously diverging color map."
CoolToWarm::usage = "Cool2Warm[n] gives the cool to warm color map, with n taking values between 0 and 1"
DivergentColorScheme::usage = "DivergentColorScheme[scheme] gives a diverging color map which interpolates between the starting and ending colors in a builtin scheme"
DivergentMaps::usage = "DivergentMaps is list of four divergent color maps used in http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/ColorMapsExpanded.pdf . divergentMaps[[1]] is equivalent to Cool2Warm" 

Begin["`Private`"]



(* 
The reference white values and transformation matrix correspond to the 
fact that in Mathematica, the RGB white point uses the D65 standard, 
while the XYZ and LAB color spaces use the D50 white point.  This is 
different than in Moreland's paper or other color conversion websites 
*)

referenceWhite = {96.42, 100.0, 82.49};


transformation = {{0.436075, 0.385065, 0.14308}, 
   {0.222504, 0.716879, 0.0606169},
   {0.0139322, 0.0971045, 0.714173}};

(*Forward Transformations*)

rgb2xyz[r_, g_, b_] := Module[
   {transm, rl, gl, bl},
   {rl, gl, bl} = If[# > .04045,
       ((# + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4,
       #/12.92] & /@ {r, g, b};
   transm = transformation;
   100 transm.{rl, gl, bl}
   ];

xyz2lab[xi_, yi_, zi_] := Module[{f, refx, refy, refz, x, y, z},
   {refx, refy, refz} = referenceWhite;
   f = If[((#) > 0.008856),
      (#^(1/3)),
      (7.787 # + 4/29.)] &;
   {x, y, z} = f /@ ({xi, yi, zi}/{refx, refy, refz});
   {116.0 (y - 4./29), 500.0 (x - y), 200 (y - z)}
   ];

lab2msh[l_, a_, b_] := Module[{m = Norm[{l, a, b}]}, {m, 
   If[m==0, 0, ArcCos[l/m]], Arg[a + b I]}];
rgb2msh[r_, g_, b_] := lab2msh @@ xyz2lab @@ rgb2xyz @@ {r, g, b};

(* Backward Transformations *)

msh2lab[m_, s_, h_] := {m Cos[s], m Sin[s] Cos[h], m Sin[s] Sin[h]};

lab2xyz[l_, a_, b_] := Module[{x, y, z, refx, refy, refz},
   {refx, refy, refz} = referenceWhite;
   y = (l + 16)/116.;
   x = a/500. + y;
   z = y - b/200.;
   {x, y, z} = 
    If[#^3 > 0.008856, #^3, (# - 4./29)/7.787] & /@ {x, y, z};
   {x, y, z} {refx, refy, refz}
   ];

xyz2rgb[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{transm, r, g, b},
   transm = Inverse@transformation;
   {r, g, b} = {x, y, z}/100;
   {r, g, b} = transm.{r, g, b};
   If[# > 0.0031308, 1.055 #^(1/2.4) - 0.055, 12.92 #] & /@ {r, g, b}
   ];

msh2rgb[m_, s_, h_] := xyz2rgb @@ lab2xyz @@ msh2lab @@ {m, s, h};

adjusthue[msat_, ssat_, hsat_, munsat_] := Module[{hspin},
   If[msat >= munsat,
    hsat,
    hspin = ssat Sqrt[munsat^2 - msat^2]/(msat Sin[ssat]);
    If[hsat > -\[Pi]/3,
     hsat + hspin,
     hsat - hspin
     ]
    ]
   ];


interpolatecolor[rgb1_List, rgb2_List, interp_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[
   {m1, s1, h1, m2, s2, h2, interpvar, mmid, smid, hmid},
   (*If points are saturated and distinct, 
   place white in the middle *)
   {m1, s1, h1} = 
    rgb2msh @@ rgb1;
   {m2, s2, h2} = rgb2msh @@ rgb2;
   interpvar = interp;
   If[s1 > 0.05 && s2 > 0.05 && Abs[h1 - h2] > Pi/3,
    mmid = Max@{m1, m2, 88.};
    If[interp < 1/2,
     {m2, s2, h2, interpvar} = {mmid, 0, 0, 2 interp};,
     {m1, s1, h1, interpvar} = {mmid, 0, 0, 2 interp - 1};
     ];
    ];
   (* Adjust hue of unsaturated colors *)

   Which[s1 < 0.05 && s2 > 0.05,
    h1 = adjusthue[m2, s2, h2, m1];,
    s2 < 0.05 && s1 > 0.05,
    h2 = adjusthue[m1, s1, h1, m2];
    ];
   {mmid, smid, hmid} = (1 - interpvar) {m1, s1, h1} + 
     interpvar {m2, s2, h2};
   msh2rgb @@ {mmid, smid, hmid}

   ];

DivergentColorFunc[rgb1_, rgb2_] := 
  With[{interp = RGBColor @@@ Chop @ (interpolatecolor[rgb1, rgb2, #] &/@ Range[0,1,.05])},
      Blend[interp, #] & ];


DivergentColorFunc[col1_?ColorQ, col2_?ColorQ] := DivergentColorFunc @@ List @@@ (ColorConvert[{col1, col2}, RGBColor]) ;

DivergentColorScheme[scheme_String] := 
  DivergentColorFunc @@ ColorData[scheme] /@ {0, 1};




CoolToWarm = DivergentColorFunc[{0.23, 0.299, 0.754}, {0.706, 0.016, 0.150}];


DivergentMaps = 
  DivergentColorFunc[#1, #2] & @@@ {{{0.23, 0.299, 0.754}, {0.706, 
      0.016, 0.150}},
    {{0.436, 0.308, 0.631}, {0.759, 0.334, 0.046}}, {{0.085, 0.532, 
      0.201}, {0.436, 0.308, 0.631}}, {{0.217, 0.525, 0.910}, {0.677, 
      0.492, 0.093}}, {{0.085, 0.532, 0.201}, {0.758, 0.214, 0.233}}};

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Now I can create a continuous divergent color map simply from two RGB colors,

```
newcolorfunc = DivergentColorFunc[{0, 0, .5}, {.5, 0, 0}];
showcolorfunction@newcolorfunc
```

[image]

Or, taking inspiration from the way J.M.'s function is defined, you can give color objects as the arguments - in any color space,

```
newcolorfunc2 = 
  DivergentColorFunc[Darker[XYZColor[1, 0.2, 1]], 
   LUVColor[.16, .5, 1]];
showcolorfunction@newcolorfunc2
```

[image]

I can use the `cool2warm` color scheme Moreland recommends,

```
showcolorfunction@CoolToWarm
```

[image]

or the other four examples listed at the bottom of [his page](http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/)

```
showcolorfunction /@ DivergentMaps[[2 ;;]]
```

[image]

I even have a function that will take a named color scheme, extract the two outer colors, and build a divergent scheme from them.

```
showcolorfunction /@ (DivergentColorScheme /@ {"RoseColors", "AvocadoColors"})
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here are those color schemes without the divergent function,

```
showcolorfunction /@ ({"RoseColors", "AvocadoColors"})
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (The best way to upload a package is Github:)

Comment: And once you've put it in GitHub, consider posting on http://packagedata.net/ too!

Comment: One comment though: it is really better to capitalize symbol names in package to ensure that user-symbols (which should not be capitalized) won't conflict with them.

Comment: BTW: no need to map `ColorConvert[]`; `ColorConvert[{col1, col2}, RGBColor]` works fine.

Comment: ahhhh, I always try to use the lowerThenUpper naming convention, didn't think that I should do differently for a package.  @Szabolcs Should I only capitalize non-private functions, and within the `Private` context, use any name I choose?

Comment: @J.M., thank you - I'm horrible for checking if a function is listable.

Comment: Well, it *doesn't* have the `Listable` attribute, but luckily it's sufficiently smart to deal with lists of colors.

Comment: "Should I only capitalize non-private functions, and within the Private context, use any name I choose?" - it's really entirely your call; Szabolcs is just mentioning that sufficiently involved public packages often use full camel case function names.

Comment: Another thing: with respect to dealing with white points, you might want to look at [this](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html). The stuff on [chromatic adaptation](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_ChromAdapt.html) might also be of interest.

Comment: Yes, what I said only applies to public functions.  If public functions are capitalized, then users of the package don't have to be extra careful not to use the same symbol names, they can just use lowercase names.  If they're not capitalized, then a package user might want to read through the list of *all* public functions to make sure there won't be trouble.  Then avoiding conflict with builtin symbols falls to the package maintainer, btu this is usually not a problem as packages tend to be carefully written, as opposed to code typed on the fly in an interactive session.

Comment: @szabolcs what about possible colisions with future releases of mma?

Comment: @Kuba That's a much smaller problem that collisions with user symbols.  New releases happen rarely.  When they do, some breakage is expected.  The package author should test the package with each new release and fix any problems.  The difference between a package and code typed during an interactive session is that a package is written with care. I put in significant effort to write the package once, then I (or possibly many other people) will use it many times. Given all that effort, it's not much more to ask to try to choose names that are less likely to conflict with builtins ...

Comment: @Kuba ... in the future and to update the package if a new release really does conflict.  But when I just work interactively, I after write code once and throw it away.  I work quickly.  I don't want to burden to have to think about what name might conflict with some large package I loaded just to use a single function from it.  This is why I think it makes sense to capitalize in *reusable* packages, but not to capitalize in user code.

Comment: At least the C standard tells the user what is not allowed. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908568/what-is-the-reason-function-names-are-prefixed-with-an-underscore-by-the-compile#comment6801901_5908708) is comment about this. [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the C-standard for reference, because it is mentioned in that comment. I would personally be in favour of *not* defining symbols that start with capitals in packages, but I do not have the most extensive experience in writing packages.

Comment: [This documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html) contains the most relevant thing I could find in the docs: "There is a convention that built‐in Wolfram Language objects always have names starting with uppercase (capital) letters. To avoid confusion, you should always choose names for your own variables that start with lowercase letters."

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I have mixed feelings about this issue. I will ask on meta, or maybe here? I don;t know where is a good place.

Comment: The only external package I've used before is scidraw (or LevelScheme), and they have all their public functions starting with uppercase - so I followed that example.  In this example, I'm not very worried that either a user or the developers will create a function that conflicts with one of those defined above.

Comment: @Szabolcs Jacob and Jason, please join the discussion: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102286/5478

Comment: I really like your answer a lot. However, I would like to get some more explanations which is good for scientific computation and why. Etc for bones and energy spectrum. - - I am not sure if there is any quantitative measure for the task.

Comment: @Masi, see [here](https://github.com/djoshea/matlab-utils/blob/master/libs/perceptuallyImprovedColormaps/Rainbow%20Color%20Map%20-Still-%20Considered%20Harmful.pdf), [here](http://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/81137_92238v00_RainbowColorMap_57312.pdf), and [here](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/the-rainbow-is-deadlong-live-the-rainbow-part-3/) for what others have written on the topic.  Personally, I like to simply try out lots of different color patterns and see which one conveys the information most effectively.

Comment: To say which color map is best for plotting on anatomical structures, I'm not really sure.  When the data is all the same sign, then I like the Parula color map, but the default color function for `DensityPlot` is also very nice.  But if the data is equally spaced around some mean value, then I like to use a divergent color map.  Also, you should read the original paper that this post is inspired by, [Diverging Color Maps for Scientific Visualization (Expanded)](http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/ColorMapsExpanded.pdf)

Comment: @JasonB I would really love to see any examples with some basic 2D data, for using `DensityPlot` in your described cases.

Comment: I found this package work perfectly for DensityPlot and ContourPlot, but NOT for Plot3D. Can you help to make it work for Plot3D as well?

Answer (score 24):

Here's my take (using some of the new version 10 functions):

```
adjusthue[msat_, ssat_, hsat_, munsat_] := hsat +
      (1 - 2 UnitStep[-hsat - π/3]) If[munsat == msat, 0., 
      Sqrt[Max[1, munsat/(msat + $MachineEpsilon)]^2 - 1]/Sinc[ssat]]

l2m = With[{m = Norm[{##}]}, {m, ArcCos[If[m == 0, 0, #1/m]], Arg[#2 + I #3]}] &;
m2l = #1 Prepend[Sin[#2] Through[{Cos, Sin}[#3]], Cos[#2]] &;

SetAttributes[interpolatecolor, Listable]; 
interpolatecolor[col1_?ColorQ, col2_?ColorQ, interp_?NumericQ] := 
     Module[{ m1, s1, h1, m2, s2, h2, mmid, t},

            {m1, s1, h1} = l2m @@ ColorConvert[col1, LABColor];
            {m2, s2, h2} = l2m @@ ColorConvert[col2, LABColor];

            t = interp;
            If[Min[s1, s2] > 0.05 && Abs[h1 - h2] > π/3,
               mmid = Max[m1, m2, 0.88];
               If[t < 1/2,
                  {m2, s2, h2, t} = {mmid, 0., 0., 2 t},
                  {m1, s1, h1, t} = {mmid, 0., 0., 2 t - 1}]];

            Which[s1 < 0.05 && s2 > 0.05, h1 = adjusthue[m2, s2, h2, m1],
                  s2 < 0.05 && s1 > 0.05, h2 = adjusthue[m1, s1, h1, m2]];

            ColorConvert[m2l @@ ({1 - t, t}.{{m1, s1, h1}, {m2, s2, h2}}),
                         LABColor -> RGBColor]]

divergentColorGradient[col1_?ColorQ, col2_?ColorQ, res_Integer: 20] := 
         With[{cl = interpolatecolor[col1, col2, Subdivide[res]]}, Blend[cl, #] &]
```

(**N.B.** the previous version of this answer used the built-in coordinate conversion functions, but they were too slow for this application. The handling for `Black` in `adjusthue[]` through a tiny perturbation is still hackish IMHO, but at least it's compact.)

Test:

```
cool2warm = divergentColorGradient[RGBColor[59/255, 76/255, 64/85],
                                   RGBColor[12/17, 4/255, 38/255]];

LinearGradientImage[cool2warm, {300, 30}]
```

[image: cool2warm gradient]

Comment: This is great!  I'm partial to the handcoded functions, since I can see what is going on, but that is just personal taste.  Your version is much more compact, but mine seems to generate a color function a bit faster (not that speed is all that important in this case).

Comment: Yes, the slowdown is apparently due to the built-in coordinate change functions; replacing them with the explicit formulae for Cartesian-spherical (that is, Lab-Msh) conversion speeds the function up considerably. At the moment, I'm looking into a less hack-ish way to handle `Black`; I'll update this post if I figure something out.