# Color a single contour from a ListContourPlot3D using values from a list

Tags: plotting, color

I want to map an electrostatic potential onto a density map.

How can I color a single contour from a `ListContourPlot3D` using the values from another list?

1. Make a 3D contour plot from a list of electron density values, of which I only need one contour.
2. Color the single contour based on the electrostatic potential density at that point. (Need help on this.)

I have this so far:

```
Den = Import["Density.dat", "Table"]; (* Contains, {x, y, z, Density} pointS *)

EP = Import["ElectrostaticPotential.dat", "Table"]; (* Contains, {x, y, z, EP} point *)

ListContourPlot3D[Den, 
  Contours -> {0.05}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[EP]]]]
```

I can't seem the find the right way to write the `ColorFunction`. Please help.

Comment: Can you include samples of your density and electrostatic potential data? Or perhaps put them into a pastebin for people to download?

Comment: Can one assume that the $(x, y, z)$ grid at which the values are calculated will be the same for the density and electrostatic potential data sets?

Comment: If you have Mathematica 10.2 or higher, you could also try [`ListSliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceDensityPlot3D.html).

Comment: I just don't see how "This question cannot be answered without additional information" is true in this case.  The question is clear, "How can I color a single contour from a ListContourPlot3D using the values from another list", given that both lists are in the form `{x,y,z, f[x,y,z]}`.  The actual data being plotted is irrelevant.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it's a duplicate of [Smooth 4D (3D + color) plot from discrete points](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50501/245)

Comment: @Jens, that does seem like a valid duplicate (and a more valid reason to close), but I would argue there's a slight difference here, in that here we have the equivalent of 5 dimensions instead of 4, but we are reducing the dimensionality to 4 by using a contour.

Comment: @JasonB Since you put in all the work already, I'll vote to re-open, too...

Answer (score 8):

In the absence of your data, I'll just use some data that I make up.  One of these is an example from the help on `ListContourPlot3D` and one is a 3D-Gaussian,

```
list1 = Table[{x, y, z, x^2 + y^2 - z^2}, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 
     1, .05}, {z, -1, 1, .05}]~Flatten~2;
list2 = Table[{x, y, z, 
     2 Exp[-3^2 ((x - .3)^2 + (y - .3)^2 + (z - .3)^2)]}, {x, -1, 
     1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}, {z, -1, 1, .01}]~Flatten~2;
```

These are structured like your data, in the form of `{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}` tuples.  Here are their contour plots,

```
ListContourPlot3D[#, Contours -> {0.3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] & /@ {list1, list2}
```

[image]

So to do this using `ColorFunction`, which is my preferred way to do it, you need to have a function to use, not a list.  We can make an interpolation function from the data, and we can use this opportunity to rescale it so that the values lie between 0 and 1.

```
 func = Module[{rescaledlist = list2},
  rescaledlist[[All, 4]] = 
   rescaledlist[[All, 4]]/Max[rescaledlist[[All, 4]]];
  rescaledlist = {{#1, #2, #3}, #4} & @@@ rescaledlist;
  Interpolation[rescaledlist]
  ]
```

[image]

And now we use this function inside the `ColorFunction`

```
ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   Hue[
    func[x, y, z]
    ]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

We can get basically the same thing from `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` but it is a bit trickier.  Look at the usage information,

```
?ListSliceDensityPlot3D
```

[image]

So we need to define a *surface* object from a `ListContourPlot3D`.  Thanks to Szabolcs for [figuring out how to do this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105653/9490).  This command gives an error, but produces the right output,

```
surf = DiscretizeGraphics@
  Normal@ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3}, 
    MaxPlotPoints -> 40];
```

[image]

Then we take some care to get the color function scaled properly, and

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[list2, surf, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#/Max[list2[[All, 4]]]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

I prefer the output by using the scaled colorfunction on `ListContourPlot3D`, and I think the workflow is simpler, but this option works as well.

On a side note, I [always](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64513/9490) [recommend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101625/9490) avoiding the rainbow color palette (be it the Jet or Hue variants).  I'm partial to the Parula color map in Matlab, which you can define in Mathematica via `<<"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sqYFdrkY";`.  If you replace `Hue[func[x, y, z]]` above with `ParulaCM[1.5 func[x, y, z]]` then you get the nice plot below

[image]

Comment: You could also just use one of Mathematica's many nice [built-in color schemes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html), like `ColorData["StarryNightColors"][func[x, y, z]]`.

Comment: That looks like a good color scheme I haven't used before. I often like to build up my own functions and don't notice the built in stuff as much