# How can I convert a 3D contour plot into a region for use as a custom slice in ListSliceDensityPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d

The documentation for [`ListSliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceDensityPlot3D.html) says

> `ListSliceDensityPlot3D[{{x1,y1,z1,f1},{x2,y2,z2,f2},…},surf]`
>   generates a slice density plot for the values $f_i$ at points $\{x_i,y_i,z_i\}$.

But what if my surface is defined only numerically?

```
list1 = Table[{x, y, z, x^2 + y^2 - z^2}, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 
     1, .05}, {z, -1, 1, .05}]~Flatten~2;
surface1 = First @ ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3}];
Graphics3D @ surface1
```

[image]

This seems clearly to be a surface, so let's try to use it in `ListSliceDensityPlot3D`:

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[
 Table[Exp[-3^2 ((x - .3)^2 + (y - .3)^2 + (z - .3)^2)],
  {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}, {z, -1, 1, .1}],
 surface1]
```

I get the error

> ListSliceDensityPlot3D::slice: "Slice specification `GraphicsComplex[<<1>>]` should be a named slice, surface or volume region, or list of slices."

and it uses the default slices

[image]

Of course in this example I could use `ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z^2==0.3,{x,y,z}]` to define the surface,

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[
 Table[Exp[-3^2 ((x - .3)^2 + (y - .3)^2 + (z - .3)^2)],
  {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}, {z, -1, 1, .1}],
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0.3, {x, y, z}],
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

but what if I don't have the equation, but only the data?  If I try to define the `ImplicitRegion` using an interpolation function it does not work.

I can't apply `DiscretizeRegion` to the contour plot, what can I do to extract the surface?

Comment: I want to have an object that I can use as a surface for `ListSliceDensityPlot3D`.  When I define `surf = First@ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3}]` and then try to use it via `ListSliceDensityPlot3D[list2, surf]` I get the error "Slice specification GraphicsComplex[<<1>>] should be a named slice, surface or volume region, or list of slices."

Comment: I will edit it to make it more clear  :-)

Comment: @Kuba - see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105623/9490), which could end up closed even though it is a valid question.  Rahul pointed out it could be done with `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` and I just want to try and do so.

Comment: @Kuba, yeah, I know there's a way to do it, I just wonder how far you can go using this new function.   *Please avoid extended discussions in comments* lol

Comment: Ahh, right, I though that is something you problably know. Well, the documentation states you can only use regions so the question can be narrowed down to "how to convert contour plot 3d to region".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to create a region using [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html).

```
g = ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3}]
```

Now `DiscretizeGraphics[g]` gets upset and refuses to work because of the `GraphicsComplex` inside of `g`. We can get rid of that using `Normal`, so let's try:

```
surf = DiscretizeGraphics@Normal[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It still gets upset because of some directives, but it appears to handle the surface part properly.  This is a region so we can use it in `SliceDensityPlot3D`:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, surf, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't try `DiscretizeGraphics` but it would have failed anyway without `Normal`.  How did you know you would have to use `Normal`?  Experience with this, or more of a workflow:  If it fails, try it with `Normal`

Comment: @JasonB The error message says that `GraphicsComplex` is not supported.  `Normal` expands the `GraphicsComplex` (see last entry under Details on its documentation page).