# How to extract data for a particular contour line in text file?

Tags: plotting

[image]

I am interested in the data for which the contour line gives 0 value in the above image. I have, of course, the data file from which I created this image but is there any way to find out the corresponding x (\Delta \Theta) and y (\Delta E) column values for the '0' contour as I don't have exactly those values in my data file? The details of my code and the data file is attached.

```
ac = Import[
  "/home/users/baban/Desktop/test.dat", "Table"]
Framed[ListContourPlot[ac, Contours -> 10, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.03, 0.05}, {10, 190}}, 
  TextStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 11, 
    FontWeight -> Bold}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]E", "\[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]"}, 
  Background -> White, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, 
      Background -> White] &), 
  ContourStyle -> Join[Table[Directive[Black], {10}]]]]
```

The data file looks like:

```
-0.05 10 0.0544900331452
-0.04 10 0.0444900331452
-0.03 10 0.0344900331452
-0.02 10 0.0244900331452
-0.01 10 0.0144900331452
6.93889390391e-18 10 0.0044900331452
0.01 10 -0.0055099668548
0.02 10 -0.0155099668548
0.03 10 -0.0255099668548
0.04 10 -0.0355099668548
-0.05 20 0.0587783048976
-0.04 20 0.0487783048976
-0.03 20 0.0387783048976
-0.02 20 0.0287783048976
-0.01 20 0.0187783048976
6.93889390391e-18 20 0.00877830489756
0.01 20 -0.00122169510244
0.02 20 -0.0112216951024
0.03 20 -0.0212216951024
0.04 20 -0.0312216951024
```

and so on...

Comment: Take a look at this question:[How to extract a contour line or a region from a ContourPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105750/27951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
dta = ImportString["-0.05 10 0.0544900331452
   -0.04 10 0.0444900331452
   -0.03 10 0.0344900331452
   -0.02 10 0.0244900331452
   -0.01 10 0.0144900331452
   6.93889390391e-18 10 0.0044900331452
   0.01 10 -0.0055099668548
   0.02 10 -0.0155099668548
   0.03 10 -0.0255099668548
   0.04 10 -0.0355099668548
   -0.05 20 0.0587783048976
   -0.04 20 0.0487783048976
   -0.03 20 0.0387783048976
   -0.02 20 0.0287783048976
   -0.01 20 0.0187783048976
   6.93889390391e-18 20 0.00877830489756
   0.01 20 -0.00122169510244
   0.02 20 -0.0112216951024
   0.03 20 -0.0212216951024
   0.04 20 -0.0312216951024", "Table"];
```

The idea here is to make a `ListContourPlot` with just one contour (the 0 value) and then extract it using `Cases`.

```
contour = Cases[Normal@
   ListContourPlot[dta, Contours -> {0}], Line[pts__] -> pts, Infinity]
(* {{{0.00449003, 10.}, {0.00614371, 13.8563}, {0.0087783, 
   20.}}} *)

Show[ListContourPlot[dta], ListLinePlot[contour, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the perfect answer!

Comment: Can I as a small favour? How to export this data for the '0' contour into a text file as I asked in the query? The desired output should in x and y column in a text file. Actually, O want to make a linear regression of that data.

Comment: @baban, Try Export["contour.txt", First@contour, "Table"]

Comment: Alright, thanks, it works!