# How to list all functions in a package?

Tags: packages, built-in-symbols

I got a package which can be loaded in MMA. The manual for the package does not give demonstrations of all functions/commands. Hoe can i find all the commands in the package?

Comment: This works for one of the built-in packages:  ``Names["NDSolve`FEM`*"]``, using the wildcard * character

Comment: And not only for built-ins, but more generally ``Names["MyPackage`*"]``. Also likely to be useful for an external package: ``Names["MyPackage`Private`*"]``

Comment: @LLlAMnYP - but then don't you need to load the package in first?  I was able to get the list of names for the FEM package without entering `Needs["...."]` first.  But for a package of my own that I have in a special folder (in the $Path) that I use for packages, I had to load it in with `Needs` before I could get the `Names`

Comment: @JasonB Yeah, that's right. I don't think, it's possible without loading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've loaded the package in with `Needs` then you can find all the included functions using `Names` with a wildcard:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
Names["VariationalMethods`*"]

(* {"EulerEquations", "FirstIntegral", "FirstIntegrals", 
"NVariationalBound", "VariationalBound", "VariationalD"} *)
```

or

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
Names["PolyhedronOperations`*"]

(* {"Geodesate", "OpenTruncate", "Stellate", "Truncate"} *)
```

This works with user-installed packages as well, like [`MaTeX`](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
Names["MaTeX`*"]
(* {"BlackFrame", "ClearMaTeXCache", "ConfigureMaTeX", "MaTeX"} *)
```

You can even use it to see the private function names, here again on a [user-defined package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101627/9490), but this one is likely to give a long list, giving any variables that are defined within scoping constructs like `Module` in the package,

```
Needs["DivergentColorMaps`"]
Names["DivergentColorMaps`*"]
Names["DivergentColorMaps`Private`*"]
(* {"CoolToWarm", "DivergentColorFunc", "DivergentColorScheme", "DivergentMaps"} *)

(* {"DivergentColorMaps`Private`a", 
"DivergentColorMaps`Private`adjusthue",......
"DivergentColorMaps`Private`rgb2msh", 
"DivergentColorMaps`Private`rgb2xyz", ..........
"DivergentColorMaps`Private`z", "DivergentColorMaps`Private`zi", \
"DivergentColorMaps`Private`z$"} *)
```