# Meta information about function parameters

Tags: meta-programming

I'm working on a project that allows for executing arbitrary, user-defined Mathematica scripts. It's an internal tool running on a trusted, local network. It's basically a web interface to Mathematica.

For every user-defined package I import, I can [run `Names` to get the list of public functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113733/35784), which I can display in a combobox. Once the user selects a function to call, I would like to have specific widgets to select the appropriate values for the arguments.

For example, `f` could have two arguments: the name of a column in a database table and a list of `WHERE` conditions. I would then show a combobox with all the column names and an expandable list of text boxes for conditions.

There's [this nifty `countArgs` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7044/35784) which I can use to get the number of parameters, but I'm stuck on adding type information on each parameter. I have two ideas right now:

- For each function `f` in a package, look for a `fMeta` and standardize a way of returning the meta information required.
- Hijack `f::usage`, embed the information there and parse it, giving something like `"name1,type1;name2,type2;;actual usage"`.

I'm probably going for the first option. Anybody has something smarter than this?

---

Here's a bit more information on the setup:

[image]

The core of the tool is a C++ program. It spawns Mma kernels running on the local machine using [WSTP](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html) and connects to a Postgres database using [`libpq`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq.html). Mma will also connect to the database using `DatabaseLink`. The C++ program also runs a fastcgi server and serves web pages as its main user interface.

As a simpler example, users can enter verbatim Mma scripts on the web page and execute them. Here's what would happen:

1. A user types the Mma code in a `textbox` on the web page and submits it;
2. It gets posted using AJAX to the C++ program, which picks it up through its fastcgi server;
3. The C++ program then passes `ExportString[ToExpression[code], "SVG"]` to Mma and sends back the SVG to the web page.

Because the results of Mma are always exported as images, I can't use any of its interactive features like `FormObject`. As for `webMathematica`, my understanding is that it's just a front end to Mma, which is too low level for me. The whole point of this tool is to give easy access to high level operations to a couple of stats guys so they don't have to copy paste from SPSS to Excel to PowerPoint to Excel to Excel to PowerPoint.

As for calling a function from the script instead of looking for a `function + "Meta"`, it's a good idea, but I haven't set up two way communication between the C++ program and Mma. I'm not even sure it's possible. I would have to check whether I can get Mma to somehow call into the C++ code, but it looks more complicated than the other way around for now.

Comment: It seems you need your own type system, with very specific requirements, which arbitrary *Mathematica* function will not fulfill. Maybe you could create your own package, and require every user defined package to import it. It could define some kind of registering function: `RegisterWebFunction[f_Symbol, argTypes_List] := ...` that would accept only very specific type declarations. Then you could display only user defined functions explicitly registered with `RegisterWebFunction`. ...

Comment: But details depend on how much, in your system, will be actually done in *Mathematica*, and how much outside. In  your web interface are you using [`FormObject`s](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormObject.html), [Wolfram Cloud](http://www.wolfram.com/cloud/), [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/)? You mentioned accessing database, are you using [DatabaseLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Overview.html)?

Comment: @jkuczm I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: In your simpler example, as I understand, there's no need for any function metadata, since web interface always has the same `textarea`. But if you want to display different widgets, based on *Mathematica* code, then you'll need to somehow transfer information from *Mathematica* to C++ (which governs interface creation), no matter how this information is stored in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @jkuczm The example was just to explain the design. I know I need to "somehow" transfer that info and since I expect Mma->C++ to be more complicated than C++->Mma, I thought calling a function by adding `"Meta"` to its name would be the simplest. If nobody else has other ideas, that's what I'll go with.

Comment: But what do you expect `fMeta` to return, and how are you planning to use it in C++?

Comment: @jkuczm It could be returning a `List[]` that can be parsed or it could even return some JSON string, it doesn't really matter. That information would be passed along to the web page where it can be handled in JS to create the appropriate widgets. In fact, JSON would make the C++ side transparent, it would just forward it to the response to an AJAX request, so that's my plan for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create special registering function that would accept function name and necessary metadata describing its arguments. In web interface you would provide only functions that were explicitly registered.

Sketch of package providing such function could look like this:

```
BeginPackage@"WebFunctions`"; Unprotect@"`*"; ClearAll@"`*"

RegisterWebFunction::usage = "\
RegisterWebFunction[f, <|\"label1\" -> meta1, \"label2\" -> meta2, ...|>] \
registers function f as web accessible, having arguments described by given \
label -> metadata entires.";

UnregisterWebFunction::usage = "\
UnregisterWebFunction[f] \
removes function f from web accessible functions.";

WebFunctionsForms::usage = "\
WebFunctionsForms[] \
returns list of active forms that, when submitted, applies registered web \
function to values from submitted form.";

Begin@"`Private`";

$webFunctions = <||>;

RegisterWebFunction[f_Symbol, argTypes_Association] :=
    AssociateTo[$webFunctions, f -> argTypes]

UnregisterWebFunction[f_Symbol] := KeyDropFrom[$webFunctions, f]

applyToAssocValues[f_] := f @@ Values@#&

WebFunctionsForms[] :=
    KeyValueMap[
        FormFunction[
            FormObject[#2,
                AppearanceRules -> "Title" -> "Function: " <> SymbolName@#1
            ],
            applyToAssocValues@#1
        ]&,
        $webFunctions
    ]

End[]; Protect@"`*"; EndPackage[];
```

Example of function registering:

```
f // ClearAll
f[x_Integer?Positive, y_?BooleanQ] := {"f function result", x, y}
f~RegisterWebFunction~<|"x" -> Restricted["Integer", {1, Infinity}], "y" -> "Boolean"|>

g // ClearAll
g[str_String] := {"g function result", str}
g~RegisterWebFunction~<|"str" -> "String"|>
```

Forms related to registered functions:

```
WebFunctionsForms[]
```

[image: print screen of forms]

Of course format of second argument of `RegisterWebFunction` and of value returned by `WebFunctionsForms` should be adapted to your needs.

Comment: I haven't forgotten this question, I just didn't get around to implementing this yet. I will eventually!

Comment: I've decided against integrating Mathematica in this project for a variety of reasons. I've accepted your answer because it is unlikely that I'll ever revisit this.