# Implementing a custom colormap

Tags: color

I have a question about how to implement a custom colormap, such as those specified on http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/. In particular I will be talking about the 'Extended Kindlmann' map, which can be downloaded on that page under Color Tables (byte) (lets say 32 values to start with).

So, I have a colormap specified by a .csv file. It has 4 columns, the first of which specifies what interval the color belongs to, the other 3 are the RGB values. I import them as follows:

```
frac = Drop[Import[
    pathName <> "extended-kindlmann-table-byte-0032.csv", {"Data", 
     All, 1}], 1];
R = Drop[Import[
    pathName <> "extended-kindlmann-table-byte-0032.csv", {"Data", 
     All, 2}], 1];
G = Drop[Import[
    pathName <> "extended-kindlmann-table-byte-0032.csv", {"Data", 
     All, 3}], 1];
B = Drop[Import[
    pathName <> "extended-kindlmann-table-byte-0032.csv", {"Data", 
     All, 4}], 1];
```

This seems to work. The question is then how one implements a custom colormap. This was studied in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753508/custom-colorfunction-colordata-in-arrayplot-and-similar-functions/9321152#9321152 for the jet colorfunction, where I found the following code for the colormap

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[
        {{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
         {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, 
                          u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

To see how this works, I plot the colorfunction

```
DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  ColorFunction -> jet,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

which looks like this
[image]

So, I thought I could just extend this to our colormap, as follows

```
ExtendedKindlmann[u_?NumericQ] := 
 Blend[Table[{frac[[i]], RGBColor[R[[i]], G[[i]], B[[i]]]}, {i, 1, 
     Length[frac]}], u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

Somehow though, this does not work. Looking at the output of the code itself it seems correct, but the colormap looks nothing like what it should:
[image]

So my question is, what is going on? Why doesn't the above work? Would you suggest a different way of implementing a colormap?

Comment: Did you remember to divide the RGB values by 255?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
colorlist = {#1, RGBColor[#2/255, #3/255, #4/255]} & @@@ (Rest@
     Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/c072b7ce4a7b4ab920b99fef716eac0d/raw/75361b760e16dadaaed2ba2df937c3a4a4a353e3/kindlmann-table-byte-0032.csv"
       , "CSV"]);
extendedKindlmann = (Blend[colorlist, #] &);
```

(I rehosted the file since i got intermittent 404 errors from the original source). Then you can view it using the `showcolorfunction` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101625/9490)

```
showcolorfunction@extendedKindlmann
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

In brief: you imported the "byte" file from Moreland's site when it's the "float" file that's in the format expected by *Mathematica*. (If you insist on the "byte" format, then you need to divide by 255, as Jason has said in comments.)

Thus,

```
With[{cl = {#1, RGBColor[##2]} & @@@ Rest[
      Import["http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/kindlmann/kindlmann-table-float-0032.csv"]]},

     kindlmann[t_?NumericQ] := Blend[cl, t] /; 0 <= t <= 1]

LinearGradientImage[kindlmann, {600, 60}]
```

[image: colormap from Kindlmann-Reinhard-Creem paper]