# Change a formula

Tags: graphics, programming, color

have a program consisting of a database of colors in L-a-b format. I want a formula to obtain the desired color by mixing different amounts of colors that are in the database.

For example: I want this color
  L: 75
  a: 3
  b: 16
In the database there are many similar numbers: For example
L: 79    a: 6    b: 22
L: 72    a: 10   b: 18
L: 80    a: 7    b: 19
etc.....
What formula can I use to make a mixture of several colors with different quantities that are in the database, the result of this mixture must be the same desired color
L: 75
a: 3
b: 16

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to Mathematica or the Wolfram Language.

Comment: Please try not to use all-capitals titles.

Comment: Similar: [How to calculate mix of 4 colors defined in CIELAB L*a*b* model?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7483/142), [The correct way to linearize colorspace before resizing, blurring etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/142)

Answer (score 5):

The weights for mixing have to be nonnegative and to sum to 1. The colors live in a three-dimensional space. So what you are looking for are barycentric coordinates in a three-dimensional simplicial complex. In general, there is no simple formula, but one can write down an algorithm to determine the mixing rates - provided that mixing is possible. Mixing is possible if and only if the color to mix lies in the convex hull of the existent colors.

Let's generate a list of random colors and

```
SeedRandom[666];
colors = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {20, 3}];
colormesh = DelaunayMesh[colors];
memberQ = RegionMember[colormesh];
```

Now, for a given color, say

```
color = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {3}];
```

we obtain a list of four colors and four mixing weights as follows:

```
color = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {3}];

If[! memberQ[color],
  Print["Warning: Color is not mixable. Computing the mixing for the \
closest mixable color instead."];
  ];

cell = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[colormesh, color];
cellcoordinates = MeshPrimitives[colormesh, cell][[1]];
result = With[{
   x = LinearSolve[
     Transpose[Rest[cellcoordinates] - ConstantArray[cellcoordinates[[1]], cell[[1]]]],
     nearest[color] - cellcoordinates[[1]]
     ]
   },
  Association[
   "MixingColorIndices" -> MeshCells[colormesh, cell][[1]],
   "MixingColors" -> cellcoordinates,
   "MixingWeights" -> Prepend[x, 1 - Total[x]]
   ]
  ]
```

> <|
>
> "MixingColorIndices" -> {19, 4, 3, 9},
>
> "MixingColors" -> {{8., 163., 61.}, {104., 116., 69.}, {73., 246., 29.}, {35., 222., 114.}},
>
> "MixingWeights" -> {0.098337, 0.0389252, 0.788665, 0.074073}
>
> |>

Test mixing:

```
 Norm[result["MixingWeights"].result["MixingColors"] - color]
```

> 0.

Great, the error is zero. Actually, there should only be a nonnegligible error, if the color `color` is not mixable; the small program above would warn you when this is the case.

The association `result` contains also the field `"MixingColorIndices"`. It is the list of integer indices of the mixing colors within the list `colors`. This might make it easier to find the shelf where the colors are to be looked up physically.